# How to download a visiting card with dynamic content?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a django app, where i wanted to provide our clients a downloadable visiting card inside their account. For that i have a user models as follows:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField()
    
    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

my url is as follows:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('visiting-card/<int:vid>', views.visitingCard, name='visiting-card'),
]
```

and i have created a view to get all the content from respective users:

```
def visitingCard(request, mid):
    user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, id=vid)
    context = {
        'user': user,
    }
    return render(request, 'visitng-card.html', context)
```

and the below code is my visting card landing page html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="main-content-body">
        <div class="row row-sm">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card crypto crypt-primary overflow-hidden">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div style="position: relative;" >
                            <img src="{% static 'dashboard/img/visiting-card-bg.jpg' %}" />
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 90px; left: 85px;" >
                            <img src="{{user.profile_pic.url}}" alt="{{user.full_name}}" style="max-width:130px;" class="rounded">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 230px;">
                            <p>
                                <strong>Name: {{user.full_name}}</strong><br>
                                <strong>Country: {{user.country.name}}</strong><br>
                                <strong>Email: {{user.email}}</strong><br>
                                <strong>Contact: {{user.contact_number}}</strong><br>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pt-3">
                            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Download Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So my question is when i click the download button, it should download the jpg file with dynamic content from the above code.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done.

You have to write an API to download images.

This API takes your back-end data out, uses PIL suite for example to make pictures, and then sends the pictures back to the front-end.

Or the front end uses, for example, canvas to make images for download.

Comment: If i add the download button, then the image under that **a tag** will download, but not with data. so the above solution won't work.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, you said that you want to download jpg files, and then the images will be downloaded but not the data, so do you want to download the jpg or the data?

Comment: Can you add the expected result and the current result?

Comment: If I still don't understand or can't solve it, I will delete the answer.

Comment: I will try to explain the whole scenario. I am generating a data through the above code. i am putting all those values over a background-image. So that users can download the whole thing. So when users download the file, it should include background image with data. Hope this will help you to understand the concept.

Comment: ok, so you want the business card made from the data, and then the picture of this business card?

Comment: Yes exactly i want that.

Comment: To update the answer, I can only provide how to make it, you have to study the actual code yourself.